# Does np.full have a deepcopy option?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-copy

I was using `np.full` to make an array of objects, but I noticed that each object was a shallow copy of the other. As a simple example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

l = np.full(5, A())
```

This gives us

```
array([<__main__.A object at 0x7fd3dcb0f290>,
       <__main__.A object at 0x7fd3dcb0f290>,
       <__main__.A object at 0x7fd3dcb0f290>,
       <__main__.A object at 0x7fd3dcb0f290>,
       <__main__.A object at 0x7fd3dcb0f290>], dtype=object)
```

And checking we can see that all A objects in the list have their attribute `a` as 1. However, if you run this line:

```
l[0].a = 10
```

Then all of the elements have their `a` attribute changed to 10. Is there any way to make `np.full` do a deepcopy or should you just go with `[A() for _ in range(5)]` or however many you need?

Comment: It looks like list comprehension is the way to go. Why do you need a Numpy array of object though (instead of a normal python list)?

Comment: It didn't necessarily need to be a numpy array I just assumed that using full would be faster than list comprehension

Comment: Unless a profiler proves otherwise I wouldn't think that. Most of the work would be running Python code (the `__init__ `method) either way. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58152117/6104191

Comment: AFAIK, Numpy wouldn't really give any runtime improvement with Objects dtype, You still have convenience of advance indexing but that's as much as you can get.

Comment: `np.full` uses `np.copyto` to copy "values from one array to another, **broadcasting** as necessary".  With object dtype, the array holds 'references', just as with a list.  So `full` is a lot like `[A()]*10]`, making a list of references to the same object.